# Java DAO on server

Tags: java, client-server, dao

Locally I attach to my DAO from my client like so;

```
try {
    AssetsDao _dao = getAssetsDao();
    Assets _result[] = _dao.findAll();
    for (int i=0; i<_result.length; i++ ) {
    display( _result[i] );
    }

}
catch (Exception _e) {
    _e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If my DAO tier is on another server, what are the methods that I can use to access this tier? I know I can create a web service and have heard I can use RMI but what is the most common method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question leaves lots of room for speculation. So you may want to expand quite a bit.

E.g. if the current implementation of your DAOs is using a database, you may as well already be able to use a different computer (i.e. server) by just adjusting your database's configuration.

*Update (taking OP's clarification into account):*

You have to come up with or (better) use an existing technique to let your client talk with your server; this has nothing to do with DAOs, though, as remotely accessing the service of DAOs is the same as accessing any other service remotely. Look at [Remoting and web services using Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#remoting). Although this is part of the spring framework documentation, it will give you a first start.

Comment: To expand. What I would like to achieve is. A server that is running the dao tier that connects to another server that is running the database. The bit that eludes me is how to connect to the dao tier from a client computer.